# Connection refused android

Tags: android, connection

I'm trying to connect in a server which is allocated at my computer from an android device.
Both are connected in the same network.
IP of my computer : 192.168.1.135
Listening at port:9000

```
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        try {

                            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.135:9000/application/login");

                            // Add your data
                            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "timestron"));
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "00000"));
                            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                            // Execute HTTP Post Request
                            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                              readStream(response.getEntity().getContent());
                              } catch (Exception e) {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                            }           
                    }
                }).start();


    ///////////////////////////////////-fin oncreate    
    }

    private void readStream(InputStream in) {
          BufferedReader reader = null;
          try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              System.out.println(line);
            }
          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
              try {
                reader.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
          }
        } 



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

I've added the sentence to obtain permissions to connect INTERNET in the manifest.xml

Error:

```
01-12 16:52:59.165: W/System.err(8406): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.1.135:9000 refused
01-12 16:52:59.165: W/System.err(8406):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
01-12 16:52:59.165: W/System.err(8406):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
01-12 16:52:59.165: W/System.err(8406):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
01-12 16:52:59.165: W/System.err(8406):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
01-12 16:52:59.165: W/System.err(8406):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
01-12 16:52:59.165: W/System.err(8406):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
01-12 16:52:59.165: W/System.err(8406):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious it's not any router-firewall related problem as you are under the same net, so there are only three possibilities:

1. There's nothing listening on that port on that IP
2. There's a local firewall on that machine that is blocking that connection attempt
3. You are not using WIFI so you're not under the same net.

Can you open that URL from your browser in your computer manually? If yes, I'd suggest using some debugging tool to trace TCP packets (I don't know either what kind of operating system you use on the destination machine; if it's some linux distribution, `tcpdump` might help).

All that assuming you have the `android.permission.INTERNET` permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: I can open the URL from the browser, I will check this tool , thanks.

Comment: Something like `tcpdump port 9000` should be enough. Then, try executing your app. If you don't see packets, that means that for some reason your connection attempt is not reaching that machine (for example, for the third reason I wrote). Otherwise, you'll have to debug either the machine where's running that web server (maybe some SELinux/AppArmor kind app blocking the access) or the code, which I think is less probable because you're not getting any exception, though.

Comment: Is there something similar for Windows?